# Android: Can I use google cloud storage API for SDK less than 26?

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to use Google's cloud storage to upload files to a bucket. I added this to my app level gradle.build:

```
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.103.0'
```

but when I try to run my app I get this error:

> MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported
>   starting with Android O (--min-api 26)

Is there any workaround to support smaller SDK's? My min SDK is 19.

Answer (score 2):

That Cloud SDK is not meant for use with Android apps.  If you want to access Cloud Storage from Android, you should use the [Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start).

Comment: I think firebase cloud storage it's much more expensive

Comment: No, the costs are exactly the same, because it's accessing the same product.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by adding:

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
```